# update with LINQ, and in operator select

Tags: c#, linq

Im tryig to transform a SP, into a linq query

This is my SP right now :

```
UPDATE PatientAlertsSummary
SET IsViewed =1 
WHERE  PatientID IN (SELECT PatientID FROM PatientTherapist WHERE TherapistID=@TherapistID)
```

I tried to make a query linq code and this is (so far) my linq query:
I came across some difficulty with doing this

```
var query = from pas in context.PatientAlertsSummaries
                         where pas.PatientID.Contains(from pt in context.PatientTherapists where pt.TherapistID == therapistid  )
                            select pas;

                        foreach (var item in query)
                        {
                            item.IsViewed = true;
                        }
```

how can I make it right ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think you've forgotten to specify the `PatientId` in this statement `from pt in context.PatientTherapists where pt.TherapistID == therapistid`. You should have put `select PatientId` at the end. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You could change the query to join on the tables to retrieve the results you want, then update the records accordingly:

```
var query = from pas in context.PatientAlertsSummaries
join pt in context.PatientTherapists on pas.PatientID equals pt.PatientID
where pt.TherapistID == therapistid
select pas;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    item.IsViewed = true;
}
```

Obviously this is untested and based on your current sql / linq query.

Comment: The select query is to get the data not to perform the update. You cannot update within the select, only whilst iterating the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    public class PatientAlertsSummary
    {
        public bool IsViewed;
        public int PatientID;
    }

    public class PatientTherapist
    {
        public int PatientID;
        public int TherapistID;
    }

    public void UpdateIsViewed(PatientAlertsSummary summary)
    {
        summary.IsViewed = true;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //UPDATE PatientAlertsSummary
        //SET IsViewed =1 
        //WHERE  PatientID IN (SELECT PatientID FROM PatientTherapist WHERE TherapistID=@TherapistID)

        var therapistId = 1;

        var patientAlertsSummaries = new List<PatientAlertsSummary>() { 
            new PatientAlertsSummary(){PatientID = 1},
            new PatientAlertsSummary(){PatientID = 2},
            new PatientAlertsSummary(){PatientID = 3}
        };

        var PatientTherapists = new List<PatientTherapist>() { 
            new PatientTherapist(){PatientID = 1 , TherapistID = 1},
            new PatientTherapist(){PatientID = 2 , TherapistID = 1},
            new PatientTherapist(){PatientID = 3, TherapistID = 2}
        };

        var updatedPatinets1 = PatientTherapists.
            Where(o => o.TherapistID == therapistId).
            Join(patientAlertsSummaries,
            patientTherapist => patientTherapist.PatientID,
            patientAlertsSummary => patientAlertsSummary.PatientID,
            (o, p) => 
                {
                    UpdateIsViewed(p);
                    return p;
                }).ToList();

    }
```